# Angular - NgClass, multiple conditions

Tags: angular, ng-class

I'm looping over an array that contains a varying amount of percentages. However, I would like to add classes based on if an answer from the database equals one of the values from the array.

The below example loops over the values in the array. What i'm trying to do is say, 'if the answer is '0', apply a class with the name 'red', if not, add a class of 'transparent'. If the answer happens to be '20', add a class name of 'amber'. If not, 'transparent'.

I seem to be hitting a wall with the multiple variations that i'm trying.

```
<div *ngFor="let percent of percentages" 
     [ngClass]="{
         (answer =='0') ? 'red':'transparent',
         (answer =='20') ? 'amber':'transparent',         
     }">
     {{ percent }}
</div>
```

**EDIT - For clarification**
What I'm attempting to do is simplify the below. This is writing each of the percentages as it's own div. What I'm attempting to do is achieve the same result but by looping through an array of percentages instead.

```
<div [ngClass]="answer==='0' ? 'red' : 'bg-transparent'"> 0% </div>

<div [ngClass]="answer==='25' ? 'amber' : 'bg-transparent'"> 25% </div>

<div [ngClass]="answer==='50' ? 'orange' : 'transparent'"> 50% </div>
```

Comment: Not everything has to go inside the template. Just create a function for it if it makes life easier for you. :)

Comment: but in your question answer is general word. so it effect all. so u need add one more property to each  element of percentages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put other condition to else option part [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkdbcy)

```
 <div *ngFor="let percent of percentages" 
         [ngClass]="(answer =='0') ? 'red': (answer =='20') ? 'amber':'transparent ">
         {{ percent }}
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time! - However, if the answer is 0, it's making all divs come back red, opposed to the single one that has an answer of 0.

Comment: Okey is your condition if 0 then red if 20 then amber else transparent ?

Comment: I've updated the question in hope of providing more clarity

Comment: but in your question answer is general word. so it effect all. so u need add one more property to each element of percentages

Comment: 'answer' is the value from the database. It feels like something like this, but multiple versions should work:  answer == percent && answer == '0': 'red'. Just not sure how to do multiple conditions for the other percentages. Do you think that'll work?

Comment: Can u put percentages array content to question also?

Comment: Yeah, I used the above syntax and added the percentages in.  [ngClass]="(answer == '0' && answer == percent) ? 'red': (answer == '25' && answer == percent) ? 'amber' : 'transparent'"

Comment: why not use the syntax {'classname':condition}?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Ternery** operator

```
<div *ngFor="let percent of percentages"
 [ngClass]="{ answer == '0' ? 'red' : answer == '20' ? 'amber' : 'transparent'}">
 {{ percent }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about moving your condition in your component rather than in template?

Something like this

```
// template
<div *ngFor="let percent of percentages" 
     [ngClass]="foo(answer)">
     {{ percent }}
</div>


foo(answer) {
   if(answer === '0') {
      return 'red';
   }
   if (answer =='20' ) { 
      return 'amber'
   }    

// add more condition here or use a switch statement above.
    return 'transparent';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! - I've updated the question for more clarity. At the moment this will apply a class of 'red' to all divs within the ngFor. When in fact, it should only be the div that has an answer of 0. Also, if my array had 20 percentage options, this function would be called 20 times?

Comment: @Haven even without a function, you will run your condition 20 times ;) that's why I used return right away so that the rest of the code won't run

Comment: not sure what you meant by this will apply a class of `red` to all divs. you can see that they'll only get a class of `red` when the answer is 0

Comment: I think i'm finding it hard to articulate the requirement. If the answer is 0, only the div that has a percentage of 0 should have a red background. All others shouldn't. Does that make sense?

Comment: have you tried my sample above? also, could you put it in stackblitz so that i could see your code

Comment: @Haven Do you mean something like this by any chance? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjz2ea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I've already marked the answer Caramiriel, but that's a pretty fantastic example, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

there're a syntax for ngClass that is {'class1':condition1,'class2':condition2...} So I think that is more indicated

```
<div class="transparent" [ngClass]="{'red':answer == '0',
                                     'amber':answer == '20',
                                     'orange':answer==50}">
```